# ngx-modialog library on angular 6, can't play a video

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an issue with my code, I'm studying step by step from a book on Angular which let you build some apps.
Well, I have been careful on writing the same things as the book on the code 
but it doesn't work.

Here's my problem.
I would like to insert through the library a dialog modal with which it's possibile to play a video and see it.
The way it should work would be through a component linked to the main component( videoplayer.ts) which has some lines where the video id is taken and used by the other component to  render the view of the modal and sanitize the link.

Here's the code

```
import { Component, OnInit ,Input, ViewEncapsulation } from 
'@angular/core';

 import { Modal} from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';
 import {VideoDialogComponent, VideoDialogContext } from './video- 
   dialog/video-dialog.component';
  import { overlayConfigFactory} from 'ngx-modialog';

 @Component({
    selector: 'abe-video-player',
    templateUrl: './video-player.component.html',
    styles:[]
    })
  export class VideoPlayerComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() videos: Array<string>;
     constructor(private modal: Modal) { }

   ngOnInit() {
         }

      playVideo(videoId: string) {
         this.modal.open(VideoDialogComponent,
         overlayConfigFactory(new VideoDialogContext(videoId)));
      }

   }
```

It's a library so I actually don't know where to pick info to make it work.
I installed it through Angualar CLI for the 5.0 version, and it works a bit, at least with no errors...

Here's the code of the modal component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SafeResourceUrl, DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DialogRef, ModalComponent, CloseGuard } from 'ngx-modialog';
import { BSModalContext } from 'ngx-modialog/plugins/bootstrap';

export class VideoDialogContext extends BSModalContext {
 constructor(public videoId: string) {
   super();
    this.size = 'lg';
  }
 }

  @Component({
    selector: 'abe-video-dialog',
    templateUrl: './video-dialog.component.html',
    styles:[]
      })
   export class VideoDialogComponent implements OnInit, 
      ModalComponent<VideoDialogContext> {
       videoId: SafeResourceUrl;
      private youtubeUrlPrefix = '//www.youtube.com/embed/';
       constructor(public dialog: DialogRef<VideoDialogContext>, private 
      sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.videoId = 
        this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.youtubeUrlPrefix 
         + this.dialog.context.videoId);
         }

       ok() {
           this.dialog.close();
        }
    }
```

The HTML of the 2 componets is a simple binding of the src property and the function playVideo() and ok(), which should play the video inserting the videoId into a sanitizing method and putting an image before the video as a thumbnail.

Any answer and advice is welcome..

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm following the same course and had the same problem. The issue appears to be the ngx-modialog version.

In the book, they specify that you should install version 5.0.0. When I tried using that, I got no response when I clicked the thumbnails.

I reinstalled ngx-modialog via npm without specifying the version, and it installed version 5.0.1. After that, the videos loaded without any problem when I clicked on their thumbnails.